# Login Failed for user 'Q_User'.The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection

Tags: sql-server-2005

Login Failed for user 'Q_User'.The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.
Where is the problem?

Comment: Does the login exist on the server? Are you entering the password correctly (it's case-sensitive)?

Answer (score 1):

Quick googling you will find

[Login failed for user 'username'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555332)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too when i was deploying a site. I was able to resolve by : REMOVING INTEGRTED SECURITY = TRUE from my connectionstring. And that was all.

If you noticed, that section was NOT included in the connectionstring your hosting provider gave you.

Like 'The Gu' will say,
Hope this helps  :)

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL Server Database is not present. It may be because of

1. SQL Server hosted by another PC and that's turn off.
2. Databse in SQL Server is not created
3. some similar issues.

Just check if the user you specified in App/Web.config has access to the Database.